# Comparing a list to a file and then counting every time that element appears in a list and putting it into a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of political parties:

```
x = ['Green', 'Republicans' 'Democrats', 'Independent']
```

and then I have a file that lists out which district was won by the political party, there are roughly sixty entries. I have some starter code but I don't quite know how to continue on.

```
def party_winners (political_party, filename):
    winning_party = {}
    with open (filename,'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            results=line.split(',')
```

Basically all I want is to compare `x`, to every single list in my file, and see if something matches so if in the file Republicans won 50 times my dictionary will say:

```
winning_party = {'Republicans':50, 'Democrats': 35, 'Independents': 0}
```

I knew I forgot something my file is a list of

```
[county, votes, political party, person who ran]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that results is a list of the winners, in the exact form that they apear in x, you could do something like this:

```
winning_party = {}
for region in results:
    if not region in winning_party:
        winning_party[region] = 0
    winning_party[region] += 1
```

This:

- Creates the empty dictionary `winning_party`
- Loops through all elements in your array of regions:

  - Checkings if the item is already in the dictionary and adds it if isn't
  - Increments the count on the item by 1

Answer (score 0):

Given a list of winners `lst`, you can use `collections.Counter` directly:

```
from collections import Counter

c = Counter(lst)
```

How you obtain `lst` depends on the structure of your csv file.